# French programming and software terminology?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, terminologie, informatique

I am trying to translate a variety of programming terminology to French. What is the best way to translate the following terms? Some are provided in example sentences for context.

1. a function
2. a method
3. to call (a function)
4. return (a value)
5. a variable
6. main function
7. to resolve (as in a JavaScript promise)
8. template
9. interface
10. object
11. API
12. block
13. line of code
14. the file is in the i18n directory
15. path (as in filepath)
16. to pass a value to a function
17. a comment
18. this structure maps country names to paths
19. a database
20. a query
21. a string
22. the request is failing
23. terminal/shell
24. operating system
25. command line
26. the computers are connected by a cable
27. a connection
28. to increment / to decrement
29. to concatenate two strings
30. to enable a feature
31. to fix a bug
32. this is passed as an argument to the function
33. the application has frozen
34. to crash (like when an application crashes)
35. header file
36. to run a script / program
37. to debug
38. the build succeeded / failed
39. a model (as in MVC)
40. to log in / to log out
41. built-in function
42. user-defined function

Comment: I would add two or three other words in this list comprehensive list: Script (tout seul) et built-in function. Also user-defined function.

Comment: Feel free to edit the question and answer as you see fit. I wanted this to be a community wiki. I guess try to be as sure as you can of the translations you provide! But that's the point, that if you're mistaken, someone else corrects you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Full credit for this answer goes to Gilles, who generously took the time to provide 98% of these translations a couple of years ago in chat. I just thought it was worth sharing, and I think it should be expanded on and perhaps made into a community-wiki. It's just very useful for anyone who is learning French and will be working in a French-speaking software environment.

1. a function → *une fonction*
2. a method → *une méthode*
3. to call (a function) → *appeler*
4. to return a value → *renvoyer/retourner une valeur*
5. a variable → *une variable*
6. main function → *la fonction* main *(la fonction principale when it is not explicitely called `main`)*
7. to resolve (like with javascript promises) → *résoudre*
8. a template → *un patron, un modèle*
9. an interface → *une interface*
10. an object → *un objet*
11. API → *une API*
12. a block (of code) → *un bloc (de code)*
13. a line of code → *une ligne de code*
14. "the file is in the i18n directory" → *le fichier se trouve dans le répertoire i18n*
15. the filepath → *le chemin*
16. to pass a value to a function → *passer une valeur à une fonction*
17. a comment (in code) → *un commentaire*
18. "this structure maps country names to filepaths" → *cette structure associe un nom de pays à chaque chemin*
19. the database → *la base de données*
20. a request/query → *une requête*
21. a string → *une chaîne de caractères*
22. the request is failing → *la requête échoue*
23. terminal/shell → *terminal/*shell *(interpréteur de commandes)*
24. an operating system → *un système d'exploitation*
25. command line → *la ligne de commande*
26. "the computers are connected by a cable" → *les ordinateurs sont reliés par un câble*
27. a connection → *une connexion*
28. to increment / decrement → *incrémenter / décrémenter*
29. to concatenate two strings → *concaténer deux chaînes de caractères*
30. to enable a feature → *activer une fonctionnalité*
31. to fix a bug → *corriger un bug/bogue [bœɡ]/[bɔɡ]*
32. "it's passed as an argument to the function" → *c'est passé comme argument à la fonction*
33. "the application isn't responding" → *l'application ne répond pas*
34. to crash → *planter / crasher*
35. header file → *fichier d'en-tête*
36. to execute / launch → *exécuter / lancer*
37. to debug → *débuguer (prononcé [debœge]) ou déboguer*
38. the build has succeeded / failed → *la compilation a réussi/échoué (mais on dit parfois « le build »)*
39. a model (as in MVC) → *un modèle*
40. to log in / log out → *se connecter / se déconnecter (aussi: se loguer/se déloguer)*
41. built-in function → *fonction intégrée (mais souvent une builtin)*
42. user-defined function → *fonction définie par l'utilisateur (peut-être existe-t-il un raccourci...)*

Comment: I don't have enougth rep to edit, but :
8. Template -> Modèle/Prototype. 12. Block -> Bloc (de code)

Comment: for 8. Template, I have sometimes read the French term "Patron".

Comment: Two typos: 16. ... à une fonction. 17. Un commentaire

Comment: 8: un patron (et non, pas prototype, c'est autre chose !), 12 un bloc.

Comment: Pourquoi ne pas avoir repris les termes anglais et mis la ou les traductions proposées à côté ? Devoir faire des aller-retours entre la question et la réponse en utilisant le numéro du mot concerné n'est pas du tout pratique. D'autre part, si 98 % du travail a déjà été fait auparavant, il serait intéressant d'avoir des liens vers la ou les questions correspondantes.

Comment: Was already planning on making that edit later tonight or tomorrow, good suggestion. I thought the same thing.

Comment: Also, the translations were done in chat, not in questions, so it's not practical to link to.