# "Inline function"

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

I was searching several sources like

[French programming and software terminology?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33677/french-programming-and-software-terminology)

What is the French term for "inline function" ? *Fonction en ligne* me paraît faux. Peut-on employer *fonction inline" ?

Comment: Dans une demande de traduction d'un terme il faut normalement présenter une définition afin de permettre des rapprochements avec le sens ou le contexte et pour permettre à des non-initiés ou à des gens qui ne connaissent pas la langue/le terme de comprendre. Ça pourrait être utile pour quiconque de savoir ce que c'est quand on a affaires à des gens qui emploient ces termes sans être développeur soi-même.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Après consultation d'un livre sur le C++ en français (auteur: Claude Delannoy, mon édition date de 2006) :

La situation n'est pas très claire : il utilise parfois

- Fonctions *inline* (italique donc)
- Fonctions en ligne
- Fonctions "en ligne" (avec guillemets donc. Sans doute pour prendre ses distances avec l'expression)

J'ai aussi consulté un vieux poly (96) de l'école IMT Atlantique, que j'avais récupéré lors d'une formation professionnelle: seule l'expression "fonctions inline" est utilisée.

J'ai aussi fait une recherche rapide sur les cours de programmation en ligne, en français: cette fois-ci l'expression "fonctions en ligne" semble dominer largement.

En bref, c'est le bazar.

Personnellement, j'utilise indifféremment l'une ou l'autre possibilité, mais ce n'est pas forcément un bon critère.

Answer (score 1):

We do say *fonction inline* for this, because of a lack of a better way to say it.

*Fonction en ligne* would usually mean "Online function".