# Développeurs logiciels, utilisez-vous souvent des anglicismes pour des mots informatiques ?

Tags: informatique, anglicismes

Par exemple, on peut dire « chaîne (de caractères) » ou *« (character) string. »*

Est-ce que vous utilisez le terme français ou l'anglicisme ?

Pour le contexte : je postule des emplois à Montréal et j'écris mon CV.

Comment: @Fólkvangr la deuxieme. Je suis developpeur logiciel, et je vais demenager a Montreal.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Is my french that bad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Étant moi-même en TI à Montréal, je peux aider, en m'appuyant sur mon expérience personnelle bien sûr.

Le CV, en tant que document officiel, devrait être tout dans une langue, ou tout dans une autre. Bien sûr les noms de technologies sont à respecter.

Ex: pour décrire une expérience passée, vous diriez "Développement de logiciel pour une firme spécialisée en impartition" et non "Développement de software pour une firme d'out-sourcing".

Bref, préparez un CV en français, un autre en anglais. Envoyez le CV selon la langue de l'affichage du poste. Mais évitez les mélanges. Lors d'un entretien, vous pourrez vous adapter au niveau de langage des gens qui vous reçoivent.

Je révise moi-même des CV pour les ressources humaines et il est bien compris que certains termes sont différents pour les candidats français. Mais l'usage de mots anglais à travers des phrases en français est assez mal vu. La position de minorité linguistique des Québécois fait que nous sommes souvent de plus ardents défenseurs du français qu'en France.

Dans mon propre CV, j'ai parfois mis entre parenthèse le terme anglais pour éviter la confusion, lors du premier emploi du terme. Ex. "Je me spécialise dans l’intégration d’intergiciels (middleware), particulièrement ..."  J'ai noté à l'usage qu'intergiciel ne passe pas toujours dans toutes les firmes, mais de plus en plus. Je réalise que ceci n'aide pas beaucoup si vous n'avez pas la connaissance du marché local.

Réalisez bien que si vous avez un CV intéressant, les gens ne vont pas faire de chichi avec quelques termes différents, les besoins sont grands pour des gens qualifiés. De toute façon une période d'adaptation est à prévoir et les employeurs le savent (ou ce sont de mauvais employeurs, n'y allez pas!)

Bonne chance dans vos recherches!

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 5):

Dans le métier, on aura plus tendance aux anglicismes, effectivement. Cela étant dû au fait que la plupart des forums d'aide sont anglophones, on aura plus facilement fait d'expliquer notre problème en ne cherchant pas à traduire les mots comme *string*, *integer* pour entier, *dashboard* pour tableau de bord, etc. Parfois le terme anglais est plus répandu que le mot traduit, par pragmatisme ; il est plus rapide de dire « un float » que  « un nombre en virgule flottante ».

Cependant, il faudra y faire attention lors des rendez-vous avec les clients (même si les commerciaux ont tendance à utiliser eux-aussi beaucoup de mots anglais, il s'agit de leur jargon, mais inversement, les termes informatiques peuvent leur paraître abscons). Je parle cependant de la situation en France métropolitaine, à voir s'il s'agit des mêmes règles à Montréal.

Answer (score 4):

Pour éviter le débat, je réponds à la question posée: oui j’utilise souvent les termes anglais quand je communique avec mes pairs francophones. Je vois cela juste comme un jargon de métier qui rend les échanges efficaces, comme si, menuisier, j’utilisais varlope au lieu de long rabot.

Comment: merci pour repondre a la question posee. Quand vous ecrivez votre CV, utilisez-vous des anglicismes? Et est-ce que votre CV est anglais, francais ou les deux?

Answer (score 1):

Non locuteur natif. Je crois que si vous utilisez les anglicismes vous serez compris par les personnes ayant un certain bagage informatique . Il existe même des cas où le terme français n'est pas autant répandu que l'équivalent anglais. Cependant, on peut souvent éviter les anglicismes :

- https://www.defensedufrancais.com/la-page-des-anglicismes/
- http://www.academie-francaise.fr/updater
- https://www.scribbr.fr/style-academique/les-anglicismes/
- https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Anglicismes_informatiques_en_fran%C3%A7ais

#### Voir aussi

- [French programming and software terminology?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33677/french-programming-and-software-terminology)

Comment: Personnellement, n'étant déjà pas fort versé dans la défense de la langue contre les anglicismes à la base, je trouve les (tentatives de) traduction française souvent risibles (ordiphone,mouchard,pourriel,...) quand elles ne dénaturent pas complètement le mot (cédérom). D'autant que leur emploi marginal les rend souvent peu claires, mais c'est un cercle vicieux forcément... Si personne ne parle d'ordiphone, ce terme aura toujours l'air incongru.

Comment: @un3hiv3r > Sans rentrer dans un débat politico-linquistiquo-philosophique, le fait est qu'en informatique on n'a pas vraiment le choix. Les language de programation sont en anglais (même si le "vocabulaire" y est limité, une condition est un *if*, pas un *si*, un entier est un *integer*), les sources d'information sont majoritairement en anglais, ou en tout cas la proportion anglais/francais est énorme, etc,...

Comment: @un3hiv3r > De plus (et là je digresse...) quand on enfile son *pyjama* ou son *anorak*, quand on mange un *yogurt* au bord d'un *fjord*, on trouve ca naturel, je ne vois pas pourquoi utiliser un *smartphone* ne le deviendrait pas... Mais c'est là un très vieux débat (même si toujours d'actualité) et si on doit en discuter, [chez cosette](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette) est certainement plus approprié comme endroit.